# Geting no response form retrofit, OpenWeather

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I apologize in advance for the quality of my code. This is my first time writing in Kotlin for Android. I have made a retrieval of the current weather from the OpenWeather api which works, but after copying the code and trying to rewrite it to receive a request for a multi-day weather probe weatherData returns me a null value.

Unfortunately, I'm already sitting on this for the second day and can't find the error.

**WeatherDataForcast.kt** I know about spelling error

```
package com.example.weatherv3

data class WeatherDataForcast(
    val cod: String,
    val message: Int,
    val cnt: Int,
    val list: List<Item>,
)


data class Item(
    val dt: Long,
    val main: MainForcast,
    val weather: List<WeatherForcast>,
    val dtTxt: String
)

data class MainForcast(
    val temp: Double,
    val pressure: Double,
    val humidity: Int,
    val temp_min: Double,
    val temp_max: Double
)

data class WeatherForcast(
    val icon: String,
    val description: String
)
```

**WeatherForcastService**

```
package com.example.weatherv3

import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Query

interface WeatherForcastService {
    @GET("forecast")
    suspend fun getWeatherForcast(
        @Query("q") city: String,
        @Query("units") units: String,
        @Query("appid") apiKey: String
    ): WeatherDataForcast
}
```

**Utils.kt**

```
package com.example.weatherv3


import android.content.Context
import android.media.MediaParser
import android.net.ConnectivityManager
import android.net.NetworkCapabilities
import android.os.Build
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException

import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

fun degreesToDirection(degrees: Int): String {
    val directions = arrayOf("N", "NE", "E", "SE", "S", "SW", "W", "NW", "N")

    val index = ((degrees % 360 + 360) % 360) / 45
    return directions[index.toInt()]
}

fun checkInternetConnection(context: Context) {
    val connectivityManager =
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

    val networkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo

    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected) {
        // Sprawdź dostęp do Internetu
        if (isInternetAvailable(connectivityManager)) {
            // Internet jest dostępny
            Toast.makeText(context, "Uzyskano dostęp do Internetu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            // Brak dostępu do Internetu
            Toast.makeText(context, "Brak dostępu do Internetu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    } else {
        // Brak połączenia z siecią
        Toast.makeText(context, "Brak połączenia z siecią", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
fun isInternetAvailable(connectivityManager: ConnectivityManager): Boolean {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        val network = connectivityManager.activeNetwork
        val capabilities =
            connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network)
        return capabilities != null &&
                (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) ||
                        capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR))
    } else {
        val networkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected
    }
}

suspend fun getWeatherData(city: String, apiKey: String): WeatherData {
    val weatherService = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(WeatherService::class.java)

    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            val weatherData = weatherService.getWeather(city, "metric", apiKey)
            weatherData // zwraca dane pogodowe
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // Tutaj możesz obsłużyć błędy zapytania lub parsowania
            e.printStackTrace()
            throw e
        }
    }
}

suspend fun getWeatherForcastData(city: String, apiKey: String): WeatherDataForcast {
    val weatherForcastService = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(WeatherForcastService::class.java)

    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            val weatherDataForcast = weatherForcastService.getWeatherForcast(city, "metric", apiKey)
            weatherDataForcast // zwraca dane pogodowe
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // Tutaj możesz obsłużyć błędy zapytania lub parsowania
            e.printStackTrace()
            throw e
        }

    }
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.weatherv3


import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val apiKey = "**myApiKey**"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        checkInternetConnection(this)

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            try {
                val city = "lodz" // Tutaj wpisz nazwę pożądanego miasta
                val weatherData = getWeatherData(city, apiKey)
                updateUI(weatherData)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                // Tutaj obsługuj ogólny błąd, np. wyświetl komunikat użytkownikowi
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            try {
                val city = "lodz" // Tutaj wpisz nazwę pożądanego miasta
                val weatherData = getWeatherForcastData(city, apiKey)
                updateUIForcast(weatherData)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                // Tutaj obsługuj ogólny błąd, np. wyświetl komunikat użytkownikowi
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun updateUI(weatherData: WeatherData) {
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewCity).text = weatherData.name
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewTemperature).text =
            "${weatherData.main.temp.toDouble()}°C"
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.wind_speed).text =
            "Prędkość wiatru:\n${weatherData.wind.speed} m/s"
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.wind_degre).text =
            "Kierunek wiatru:\n${degreesToDirection(weatherData.wind.deg)}"
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.pressure).text =
            "Ciśnienie:\n${weatherData.main.pressure} hPa"
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.humidity).text =
            "Wilgotność:\n${weatherData.main.humidity}%"
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.temp_min).text =
            "Temperatura minimalna:\n${weatherData.main.temp_min}°C"
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.temp_max).text =
            "Temperatura maksymalna:\n${weatherData.main.temp_max}°C"
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.description).text =
            "${translateWeatherDescription(weatherData.weather[0].description)}"
        val iconUrl =
            "https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${weatherData.weather[0].icon}@4x.png"
        Glide.with(this)
            .load(iconUrl)
            .into(findViewById(R.id.imageViewWeatherIcon))
    }

    private fun updateUIForcast(weatherDataForcast: WeatherDataForcast) {
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView).text = weatherDataForcast.list[1].weather[0].description
    }
}
``
```